# IE not showing a bmp image with x-content-type-options header

Tags: html, internet-explorer, mime-types, content-type

Our server side serves images using "X-Content-Type-Options": nosniff header to prevent mime type sniffing by browsers.

Now when i embed/reference the image in an html file, then it does not open in Internet explorer.

Sample here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G180IFYZL1IS

This problem is only happening with bmp files with mime type (image/bmp) and in internet explorer.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: The purpose of `<img>` is to embed an image. I'm not surprised if it doesn't do anything else. To create a link you use `<a>`; it's by no mean restricted to HTML documents.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks for the reply...can you please check my update to the post above ?

Comment: The update looks like an entirely new question. Internet Explorer used to ignore `Content-Type` and insist on figuring out file type from the URL, so stuff like e.g. `<a href="/show_avatar.php?user_id=31415">See picture</a>` (or right-clicking on a `<img>` tag to download the file, if I recall correctly) some times didn't work as expected. If this question is really about solving a specific problem in a codebase that needs to support IE then I think it'd be most straightforward to describe the issue itself.

Comment: Apologies for updating the same question...i have updated the complete question now

Answer (score 0):

> Does img tag overlooks the content-disposition headers?

Yes.

The HTML says "Show an image here".

It isn't a case of navigating to a URL and then trying to decide if it is best to show it inline or download it.

Comment: Thanks.. but the issue seems to be with the x-content-type-options header

Comment: @saurav — What issue? You have a number of rather unclear statements in your question. The only actual clear question in it is answered in this answer.

Comment: Apologies for updating the same question...i have updated the complete question now

Comment: For testing purpose, Can you try to save your bmp file with mime content type 'image/jpeg'? It may help to work around this issue. I also suggest you to do not create duplicate threads for the same issue. (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708491/linked-image-is-not-displayed-in-internet-explorer (2) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/52fe1131-8c95-4471-b7ab-d75d39e41004/linked-image-is-not-displayed-in-internet-explorer?forum=iewebdevelopment If possible for you than delete these threads and try to continue your discussion on this thread. Thanks for your understanding