# IE not rendering a bitmap image with x-content-type-options header

Tags: internet-explorer, mime-types

Our server side serves images using "X-Content-Type-Options": nosniff header to prevent mime type sniffing by browsers.

Now when i embed/reference the image in an html file, then it does not open in Internet explorer.

Sample here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G180IFYZL1IS

This problem is only happening with bmp files with mime type (image/bmp) and in internet explorer.

Best Regards,
Saurav

PS: Creating a new post since the older post was not clear enough

[IE not showing a bmp image with x-content-type-options header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54733237/ie-not-showing-a-bmp-image-with-x-content-type-options-header)

Comment: I did not see any changes in your original post as compare to the other thread. If your posts are not clear than you can try to update your posts on the same threads and continue the discussion. I can see you had created many duplicate threads for the same issue. (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54733237/ie-not-showing-a-bmp-image-with-x-content-type-options-header (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708491/linked-image-is-not-displayed-in-internet-explorer (3) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/52fe1131-8c95-4471-b7ab-d75d39e41004/

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT created different posts because the initial RCA i had done was different and the answers were getting confused...

Comment: This issue with IE would not get fixed. It is advisable to use MS Edge. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/20559255/

Comment: yes...just to update...this works with Edge